# Apache mod_mono settings for multiple MVC apps without editing apache config

Tags: apache, mono, raspberry-pi, mod-mono, raspberry-pi3

I am setting up a mono server using Apache and mod_mono on the Raspberry PI 3 running Raspbian Jesse. I already have mono and mod_mono installed and functioning properly.

This is my desired folder structure

- /var/www/html

  - App1
  - App2

I would like to configure Apache so that I can simply copy a new .NET mvc3 app into a folder directly beneath /var/www/html, (i.e. /var/www/html/App1), and each of those applications will automatically start working as MVC3 apps without having to add an entry to the apache config for each application.

`MonoAutoApplication enabled` does not work in this case because I am not serving .aspx pages (or any other .net file), but rather these are MVC applications.

The benefit of this approach is that I can keep this config file with each application in version control. Then when starting a server from scratch, there is less configuration that needs to be done when deploying the apps.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few assumptions are made here.

- Apps will only be published directly beneath /var/www/html. For example, /var/www/html/app1, /var/www/html/app2
- Each app will provide a mod_mono.conf file in its root folder. For example, /var/www/html/app1/mod_mono.conf
- The mod_mono.conf for each app must know the absolute path to the app.
- The apache server must be reloaded after deploying a new app. There's not really a way around this.

At the end of apache2.conf, add the following:

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```bsh
#define the default mono server
MonoServerPath default /usr/bin/mod-mono-server4
#include all config files from all mono apps
IncludeOptional "/var/www/html/*/mod_mono.con[f]"
#prevent web access to mod_mono.conf files
<Files ~ "mod_mono.conf">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

and then for each application, add this mod_mono.conf, changing the path to the folder accordingly
/var/www/html/app1/mod_mono.conf

```
AddMonoApplications default "/app1:/var/www/html/app1"
<Location /app1>
    SetHandler mono
</Location>
```